# Strange character on saving data in mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

When I save data from the form the data is stripped and strange characters are appended with data.
I can't figure it out from the code. It was working fine and suddenly happened this thing. 
code is written in PHP

when I enter `makhdoomfahim@yahoo.com`

in the database table it saves as in the following image.
[image]

Comment: can you please provide the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in php `trim` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) before passing the variable to mysql. Also you have to make sure that your mysql table is utf8_general_ci.

Example:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$mail = trim($_POST['email']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (email) VALUES (".$mail.")");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Also keep in mind the `mysql_real_escape_string` for securing the variables you insert in your database.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Unicode replacement character eg see [Removing unwanted character from column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991284/removing-unwanted-character-from-column) for further info

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did not use utf8_encode($input).Try this and see if your error is rectified.