# SQL column with email body and chart conversations with lot of spaces - how to clean

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, data-cleaning

I have a SQL query outputting a column which contains data from emails and chart conversations with lot of spaces, special characters, how can I clean and make this data show up in one row so that I could save the table output into a CSV file. 
PS: the query output is in millions.

Comment: SQL Server, and any database in general, probably isn't the best place to do this cleanup.  I vote for handling this in your app layer.

Comment: I agree, but i need to provide a data extract so any work around ?

Comment: Please provide the query

Comment: @DanielMarcus its a simple select query with few joins, so i loaded the query output into a temp table, and I'm trying something like this to remove those blackspaces, tabs etc.                                      WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.YourTable
    SET Column = Replace(Column, Substring(Column, PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', Column), 1), '')
    WHERE Column LIKE '%[^0-9.-]%'
    If @@RowCount = 0 BREAK;
END;

Comment: You dont need to run a loop for this - also I'd throw in some ltrim rtrims too - its possible you also have some special characters in which case this might be tough - id do a search for sql hidden charachters if i was you

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991284/removing-unwanted-character-from-column) could help. Instead of the space character use just empty quotes as the third parameter.